# Maven not updating/downloading dependencies

Tags: eclipse, apache, maven, wicket

I'm using Eclipse EE and Apache Wicket.

I have my dependencies written down at pom.xml.

For some reason, maven is not updating even when I try to clean the project and go under Maven > Update Project.

When I go to check the dependencies the jar is there, but it still give me error when I try to run (ClassNotFoundException).

Why is this happening?

Dependency in question:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
    <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Also already tried to reinstall maven.

Comment: Depending on your installation of maven... check if there are two repositories, one from the maven installation inside Eclipse and one from a possible maven installation outside Eclipse

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try running *mvn eclipse:eclipse* to update ur Eclipse.
Also, refresh after completion of the command run.

Comment: This was a vital step, but there were also shitloads of things screwed up (my own fault) when I pulled from github. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ComicSansMSLover I am facing the same issue when I import the project from GITHUB. Can you tell me what it is?

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't mix "mvn eclipse:eclipse" and [m2eclipse maven eclipse plugin](http://www.sonatype.org/m2eclipse/), it will cause the plugin to not operate correctly. If you have done so, you need to remove your .project/.classpath/.settings files and re-import with "import existing maven projects".